# CakePHP add event listener

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm struggling to get the final link in a CakePHP (v3.x) event working. In my Controler `add` method I have public function

```
add() 
{
      $event = new Event('Model.Comment.created', $this, [
            'comment' => $comment
      ]);
      $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
}
```

and have my listener class set up:

```
namespace App\Event;

use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Event\EventListener;

class CommentListener implements EventListener {

public function implementedEvents() {
    return array(
        'Model.Comment.created' => 'updatePostLog',
    );
}

public function updatePostLog($event, $entity, $options) {
     Log::write(
    'info',
    'A new comment was published with id: ' . $event->data['id']);
}
}
```

But can't get the listener set up correctly, particularly with my app knowing that my `CommentListener` class exists.

Comment: is it displaying some error or warnings?

Comment: No, the runs, but I it doesn't do anything, I know I'm missing the bit that ties the two together and I'm not sure how it's implemented.

Comment: Looking at the docs:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners

I'm confused where these lines go: 
// Attach the UserStatistic object to the Order's event manager
$statistics = new UserStatistic();
$this->Orders->eventManager()->on($statistics);

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue, then I found this post:
[Events in CakePHP 3 – A 4 step HowTo](http://web.archive.org/web/20200105194759/http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/09/01/events-cakephp-3/)

It really cleared things up for me and describes that last linking step that you are needing. Assuming that your Listener class is in the `Event` folder under `src` of your app, all you need to do is step 4 in the article, I've adapted their code example to your example:

> Lastly we have to register this listener. For this we will use the globally available EventManager. Place the following code at the end of your config/bootstrap.php

```
use App\Event\CommentListener;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

$CommentListener = new CommentListener();
EventManager::instance()->attach($CommentListener);
```

The above is a global listener. It's also possible to register the event on the Model or Controller+Views layer as per the CakePhp docs ([CakePHP 3.x Events System](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html)). It suggests between the lines that you can register the listener on the layer you require - so possibly the `AppController` on the `beforeFilter` callback or `initialize` method, although I've only tested the `beforeFilter` callback.

**Update as of CakePHP 3.0.0 and forward**

The function `attach()` has now been deprecated. The replacement function is called `on()` and therefore the code should look like this:

```
use App\Event\CommentListener;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

$CommentListener = new CommentListener();
EventManager::instance()->on($CommentListener); // REPLACED 'attach' here with 'on'
```

Comment: See http://web.archive.org/web/20200105194759/http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/09/01/events-cakephp-3/ for a copy of the URL in the answer that is now unavailable.